# Trying to draw lines in java over an image i already drew but i can't get it on top of the image?

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, shapes

I have to draw an archery target with two black lines in the innermost circle that forms a cross, but every time i adjust the lines so that the lines are closer to the centre it goes behind the image instead of appearing on top. How can I stop this? Does it need to have a separate set of instructions entirely?

This is my code:

```
package sumshapes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SumShapes extends JFrame 
    implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel panel;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(250, 200, 250, 200);
        g.drawOval(140,90,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(140,90,200,200);
        g.drawOval(162,109,155,155);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(162,109,155,155);
        g.drawOval(183,129,112,112);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(183, 129, 112, 112);
        g.drawOval(210,153,60,60);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(210, 153, 60, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumShapes frame = new SumShapes();
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout (new FlowLayout());


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
        paper.drawLine(20,80,120,80);




    }




}
```

Comment: 1. Don't override paint - override `paintComponent` of a lightweight component 2. You should be calling the parent method eg `super.paintComponent(g)` 3. There should  never be a need to call `getGraphics` on a `JPanel`. You drawing should go into `paintComponent`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Answer (score -1):

1. All your drawing should go into the `paintComponent` method of a lightweight component, such as a `JPanel`.
2. There should never be a need to call `getGraphics`. If you wish to change the drawing upon a particular action you should a) program the logic into `paintComponent` b) alter the logic in the Action c) call `repaint` on the Component

For example:

```
private JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);//call parent method first thing
        //paint here
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){//provided so you can size this component as necessary
        return new Dimension(500,400);
    }
};

....
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
```

As an aside, I'd recommend placing all calls to to Swing components on the EDT - this means wrapping your Swing calls in the main method with SwingUtilities. eg

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
             SumShapes frame = new SumShapes();
             ....
        }

    });

}
```